# How to store JSON data in a meaningful way in Oracle

Tags: sql, json, oracle, twitter

Using Twitter API, I can get tweets like this :

```
{
      "coordinates": null,

      "created_at": "Mon Sep 24 03:35:21 +0000 2012",
      "id_str": "250075927172759552",
      "entities": {
        "urls": [

        ],
        "hashtags": [
          {
            "text": "freebandnames",
            "indices": [
              20,
              34
            ]
          }
        ],
        "user_mentions": [

        ]
      },
      "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
      "contributors": null,
      "text": "Aggressive Ponytail #freebandnames",
      "metadata": {
        "iso_language_code": "en",
        "result_type": "recent"
      },
      "retweet_count": 0,

        "profile_background_color": "C0DEED",
        "verified": false,
        "geo_enabled": true,
        "time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
        "description": "Born 330 Live 310",
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "profile_background_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
        "statuses_count": 579,
        "friends_count": 110,
        "following": null,
        "show_all_inline_media": false,
        "screen_name": "sean_cummings"
      },
      "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
      "source": "Twitter for Mac",
      "in_reply_to_status_id": null
    }
```

You can see that this data is perfect for MongoDB, you can easily write the data to there. I want to store this data on an SQL db like Oracle. I don't know how to store nested parts like :

```
 "entities": {
            "urls": [

            ],
            "hashtags": [
              {
                "text": "freebandnames",
                "indices": [
                  20,
                  34
                ]
              }
            ],
            "user_mentions": [

            ]
```

Can you tell me how I should write such properties on Oracle? Should I create a new table for each nested property(which I am unwilling to do) or is there another way? Is there a magical such that I can store all Tweet data in one place like it's done on NoSQL? Thanks.

Comment: Oracle does support `object types`, therefore you can use pre-defined object types or design your own and use them as a table column for example. This data looks like JSON, but I do not know if there is a pre-defined JSON type.

Comment: Guess you don't want to store the message and to forget it. So the primary question is how the data will be processed. It's all about business transactions and views which the Db should facilitate with its indices and other stuff the Db is intended to help users with.

Comment: Oracle 12c added [JSON support](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm); in earlier versions you can use a third-party [PL/JSON](https://github.com/pljson/pljson) package and treat the raw JSON as CLOBs. But it isn't clear if you want to store the whole thing as-is, or if you want to extract relational data from it - as Serg said, it depends what you'll do with the contents really.

Comment: @AlexPoole I want to store whole document and I want to make queries on that document such as ` "profile_background_color": "C0DEED"`.

Comment: OK, so how you'll do that depends on the Oracle version. It's built-in in 12c so store as JSON data type there; before that store as CLOB and use that third-party package or roll your own if that isn't allowed. SO which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: @AlexPoole It's 12c.

Comment: OK, then I already [linked to the documentation for JSON handling](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6246). There's way too much to try to put into an answer here though.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.